# {% load gTTS %} in template make mistake 'gTTS' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, gtts

I make a quiz app with Django I want to add text-to-speech advantage with google I recive the below error message:

```
gTTS' is not a registered tag library
```

when I write in the template

```html
{% load gTTS %}
<audio
    src="{% say 'en-us' {{question.question}}  %}"
    controls
></audio>
```

I install **`gTTS`** and I add a line in **`setting.py`**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'gTTS',
    ...
```

I make the application **`gTTS`** without any code on it I depend on this page [django-gtts-pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Django-Gtts/), Why did not work?

Comment: did you migrate after adding gTTS to installed apps?

Comment: thank you for your replay i make python manage.py makemigrations gTTS
python manage.py migrate gTTS the responce is No changes detected in app 'gTTS' and No migrations to apply.

Comment: have you installed gTTS using pip

Comment: i make it before i make python manage.py startapp gTTS